# Which databases should be replaced in connectionstrings when upgrading?

Tags: upgrade

I'm upgrading from Sitecore 9.3 to 10.2.

As per the documentation, I ran some upgrade scripts for some of the databases (e.g. core, master, web, and others), and some other databases didn't require an upgrade script (e.g referencedata, processingenginestorage, exmmaster)

The documentation mentioned in 3.2.2

> connect the new Sitecore XP instance to the databases from previous Sitecore XP version that you upgraded in the previous chapter.

so my understanding is that I should only connect 9.3 databases to my new 10.2 instance that had any upgrade script run on them, and keep using the new 10.2 databases for any DBs that had no upgrade script run on them.

However, when I checked the contents of the 9.3 referencedata database for example, I found that there is some data there, wouldn't that mean this data will be lost if I use the new 10.2 referencedata DB?

My question is mainly: which databases should be replaced with the upgraded databases in the connectionstrings.config file when we are upgrading, and which ones should be left to reference the fresh 10.2 instance databases?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you want to take changes to only master, web and core database then yes use vanilla databases for other Dbs.

But if you want to keep changes in Analytics data then there are separate steps to upgrade Analytics DB (xDB). For reference use the this - [How to handle xDB during a Sitecore upgrade?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/808/how-to-handle-xdb-during-a-sitecore-upgrade)

If you want to keep Reference DBs updates then there are other steps to upgrade that DB. For reference use this - https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2022/03/15/sitecore-speeding-up-the-upgrade-process-for-the-reference-data-database/

To upgrade the xDB Reference Data database:

1. Run the `SXP_referencedata_Part1.sql` script.
2. Review the results of running the script. If you receive the following message:

Definitions cannot be migrated. Length of # definition monikers exceeds 300 characters.
Consider truncate, change or remove them. Upgrade stopped. Fix all the issues and run this
script again. Upgrade (part 1) has not been completed.

Fix all the issues as described in this message and run the
SXP_referencedata_Part1.sql script again.
Repeat this step until you receive the Upgrade (part 1) has been done successfully.
message.

3. Run the `SXP_referencedata_Part2.sql` script

So it totally depends on the business decision. Generally, we just need to upgrade master, core databases if the client doesn't want to have analytics then we keep new one as is.

For more reference you can see the [blog](https://sitecorepro.com/sitecore-10-2-upgrade-guide/)

And in [Sitecore 10.2 upgrade guide](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/0AA18F7EE15F47A2827516C753C5E89D.ashx?date=20230220T111712), you can find each information in details -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of `Sitecore XP` you are upgrading from, you must upgrade some existing databases and deploy some new ones. The database upgrade scripts contain the changes that must be applied to the Sitecore
databases to align them with the new version. They also modify certain tables and collections to
support new functionality and improve performance.  Run the `Sitecore 10.2` Upgrade scripts from `9.3` to `10.2`. The following scripts are applicable for the `9.3` to `10.`2 upgrade

- CMS_core
- CMS_core_master_web_9x
- CMS_master.sql
- CMS_security.sql
- CMS_web.sql
- SXP_collection_GrantPermissions.sql(Run on both Shard0 and Shard1 databases)
- SXP_collection_Part1.sql (Run on both Shard0 and Shard1 databases)
- SXP_collection_Part2.sql (Run on both Shard0 and Shard1 databases)
- SXP_experienceforms_filestorage.sql
- SXP_experienceforms_storage.sql
- SXP_marketingautomation.sql
- SXP_processing_engine_tasks.sql
- SXP_reporting.sql
- SXP_reporting_migrate_experience_optimization_data.sql

Refer to this blog for more upgrade steps.

[sitecore-10-2-upgrade-guide](https://sitecorepro.com/sitecore-10-2-upgrade-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

We have recently upgraded from 9.3 to 10.2, based on the Sitecore upgrade guide you have to upgrade the following scripts

Run the Sitecore 10.2 Upgrade scripts from 9.,3 to 10.2. The following scripts are applicable for the 9.3 to 10.2 upgrade

**Core DB**

CMS_core
CMS_security.sql

**Core Master and Web DB**

CMS_core_master_web_9x

**Master DB**

CMS_master.sql

**Web DB**

CMS_web.sql

**Shard0 and Shard1 DB**

SXP_collection_GrantPermissions.sql(Run on both Shard0 and Shard1 databases)

SXP_collection_Part1.sql (Run on both Shard0 and Shard1 databases)

SXP_collection_Part2.sql (Run on both Shard0 and Shard1 databases)

**Experience Forms DB**

SXP_experienceforms_filestorage.sql

SXP_experienceforms_storage.sql

**Marketing automation DB**

SXP_marketingautomation.sql

**Processing DB**

SXP_processing_engine_tasks.sql

**Reporting DB**

SXP_reporting.sql

SXP_reporting_migrate_experience_optimization_data.sql

I have also written a step by step guide to upgrade from 9.3 to 10.2 in my blog here

https://sitecorepro.com/sitecore-10-2-upgrade-guide/

Hope this helps!